# How can I make my grid collapse with the last item on top and first item on bottom?

Tags: css

I have a grid that collapses columns into rows using this trick

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
```

I want it to collapse in a way to where the first item goes to the bottom.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a media query, example:

```
  @media (max-width: 200px) {
    .box-2 {
      order: -1
    }
  }
```

this says that when the parent container goes below 200px, the class of box-2 gets sent backward